# Subdomain implementation (c#, asp.net, mvc5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, subdomain

I am thinking about **Implementing an admin subdomain** - for testing purpouses on the localhost.

I've been thinking, and it Would be preferable if the subdomain had its own set of controllers in different folder (f.e. *Controllers/SUBDOMAIN_NAME/newHomeController.cs)* or that it would be different part of the web working with the same models and database.

Everything I have read so far included quite big code of, for me as a newbie, magical routing, often leaving the link creating, so much needed in views, unanswered.
Other way I have heard of is to develope it as another project, but that doesnt seem to be the way to go, especially if I want it to be at least a part of the project (same models and db).

I can imagine I am not the first doing that and that this might be VERY common intension so I hope there might be a SIMPLE way to do it (including creating links in view)

I would appreciate any insight into a complete solution of this "problem".

Comment: Have not used MVC 5, and don't have time for a full answer but we do this with [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx). If I have time later I'll followup with details.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Thanks, would appreciate the details :)

Comment: Yes, areas would be the best option for this.